# running shell command from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have jenkins pipeline job configured for one repo. From jenkinsfile i am running command like

```
statusCode = sh (script: "java -jar assembly.jar --file 
${workingDir}/excel/Case-Metadata.xlsx --name ${workingDir}/opCo.json --json 
${workingDir}/opCo.json --pot opCo.pot", returnStatus: true )
//printing value of statusCode as
sh "echo 'command status is ${statusCode}'"
if (statusCode != 0)
{
   currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
   error "Shell command failed"
}
```

When i run the job, it throws error like

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at FXSheet$$anonfun$getcaseCategories$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$26$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$27.apply$mcVI$sp(FXSheet.scala:969)
```

and value of statusCode is coming as '0' even though command is failed.

Comment: It sounds like a possible problem in the `assembly.jar` not throwing an exception to exit the program with the correct exit code.

Comment: I agree with mkobit. This appears to be a problem with assembly.jar, not the Jenkins shell step.

Comment: how can i make jenkins build failed if there are any errors like java.lang.nullpointerException

Comment: that error is gone after doing some changes to source file and generating jar file. But i might not know in which part of code that issue happens in advance. So i want write a condition such that if that nullpointerexception happens during build i want to make build failed. so that i can check that some issue happened. otherwise if build status is green then i dont know that issue is there